# Tmux send-keys removing semicolon

Tags: shell, tmux

The following command:

```
tmux send-keys -l -t 1 'foo;'
```

Sends only `foo` to the pane. If I send `foo;;` I get `foo;`. If the semicolon is in the middle of the string this does not happen.

How to send things literally?

*Note: I'm using this command as a way to send code to REPL's, so its not feasible to split in many commands or escape just parts of the string.*

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
tmux send-keys -l -t 1 'foo\;'
```

Comment: If you intention is to run multiple commands in one send-keys command, you can try something like  

tmux send-keys -t 0 'echo foo' Enter 'echo foo2' Enter

Comment: The problem is that escaping in the middle of the string produces the escaping sequences as literals. I need a escape all or nothing solution. I added the context on the post to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that both the shell *and* `tmux` use `;` as a command separator. When you run

```
tmux send-keys -l -t 1 'foo;'
```

the `tmux` command sees this as a single `send=keys -l -t 1 foo` command terminated by a `;`, whereas

```
tmux send-keys -l -t 1 'foo;;'
```

sees the command `send-keys -l -t 1 foo;` terminated by a `;`. That interpretation sounds a little suspect, but it is backed up by the following

```
tmux send-keys -l -t 1 'foo;' send-keys -l -t 1 'bar'
```

being the same as

```
tmux send-keys -l -t 1 'foobar'
```

Unfortunately, you will just need to keep this in mind when constructing your argument to `send-keys`: argument-final semicolons are `tmux` command terminators and need to be escaped; other semicolons do not need escaping.